# Trouble installing ZF2 from git

Tags: php, git, zend-framework2

I am installing ZF2 on wamp.

I run 
`php composer.phar self-update`

It works fine but

when I run `php composer.phar install`

I am getting error as

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://nodeload.github.com/zendframework/zf2/zip/release-2.2.1" file 
 could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Unable to find the socket tr
  ansport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?`

I have `curl` and `open ssl` enable for php.

I searched but cant find any working solution .

Any suggestions or workaround ?

Thanks

Comment: Check that SSL is enabled in php.ini. If you enabled the modules via wamp then I think they are not enabled when running php via the command line.

Comment: Also, have you setup your composer.json correctly to install the zip file? Can you post your composer.json file, or at least the relevant repositories/require sections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should make sure that you are calling the PHP version installed with WAMP instead of any other versions you have installed. 
On windows use

```
where php
```

in the cmd prompt. You should get the wamp directory. If not then you might not be calling the right php version. I sometimes get confused with the *nix machines. You can also try `which php` if `where` doesn't work on the windows box.

You're a high scorer so you probably got that covered.

Besides that, run

```
php --ri openssl
```

AND

```
php --ri curl
```

to see the status of the extensions. If you get something saying

```
Extension [ext-name] not present
```

you have to enable them in the php.ini

Comment: Sorry for late reply .. `php --ri openssl` shows extension not present but it is enabled in php.ini. And I am windows xp user so `where` command is not available for me

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say `which php` on windows. I always get confused between the two.